# Pandas read_csv add header names in case of changing number of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a lot of csv files that I would like to read with Pandas (pd.read_csv), however, in some of the files there is added a column midway that does not have a header, like this example:

```
Apples, Pears
1, 2
3, 4
5, 6, 7
```

If using pd.read_csv(example_file) the following error is thrown "*ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 4, saw 3*"

I would like to avoid having to skip the line and instead just add a dummy header name, like Unknown1, and get the following result:

```
Apples, Pears, Unknown1  
1, 2, np.nan
3, 4, np.nan
5, 6, 7
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pandas` needs to know the geometry in advance to build the dataframe. You can read the header line and add several dummy column names to supply the number of columns, then re-read the whole csv and discard the columns that weren't used after all.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> names = list(pd.read_csv('foo.csv', nrows=0)) + ['unknown1', 'unknown2']
>>> df=pd.read_csv('foo.csv', names=names, skiprows=1).dropna(axis='columns', how='all')
>>> df
   Apples   Pears  unknown1
0       1       2       NaN
1       3       4       NaN
2       5       6       7.0
```

If there are many extra columns and you are worried about the memory footprint of the intermediate dataframe, you can use the `csv` module to scan the file and calculate the maximum number of rows. Unlike `pandas`, `csv` is quite happy to emit varying sized rows.

```
>>> with open('foo.csv', newline='') as in_fp:
...     reader = csv.reader(in_fp)
...     header = next(reader)
...     num_cols = max(len(row) for row in reader)
... 
>>> names = header + ['unknown{}'.format(i+1) for i in range(num_cols-len(header))]
>>> df = pd.read_csv('foo.csv', names=names, skiprows=1)
>>> df
   Apples   Pears  unknown1
0       1       2       NaN
1       3       4       NaN
2       5       6       7.0
```

Comment: Excellent! Nice and simple, and only uses Pandas. Thank you! :)

Comment: I am afraid this is not scalable. What do you do if there are 10 missing column names?

Comment: @sudonym - It really depends on what level of scaling you need. Preprocessing the file adds to CPU cost. The memory footprint is not that big of a deal on modern hardware unless the files are quite large. OP has many files and few extra columns. It is likely a good solution.

Comment: I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

We can load the csv then fixed your out after that

```
import io
t="""Apples, Pears
1, 2
3, 4
5, 6, 7"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep='\t')

yourdf=df.iloc[:,0].str.split(', ',expand=True)
s=df.columns.str.split(', ').tolist()[0]
yourdf.columns=s+['unknow'+str(x+1) for x in range(yourdf.shape[1]-len(s))]


yourdf
Out[104]: 
  Apples Pears unknow1
0      1     2    None
1      3     4    None
2      5     6       7
```

Comment: In the case of 't' being a path to the csv file, how would IO be used?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the number of columns beforehand, you can determine the maximum number of columns across all rows beforehand using `readlines()`, which comes at the cost of loosing the known header names.

```
sep = ','                                                   # Define separator
lines = open("test.csv").readlines()                        # Open file and read lines
colcount = max([len(l.strip().split(sep)) for l in lines])  # Count separator
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", names = range(colcount), skiprows = [0])
print df

   0  1    2
0  1  2  NaN
1  3  4  NaN
2  5  6  7.0
```

The `colcount` above can be applied to all other answers so far, too.

---

Edit: Beware of input files other than .csv (see comments)

Comment: This doesn't work either. You've ignored any quoting and escapes for the column separator that a CSV processor would consider.

Comment: this works for me - did you copy and paste into jupyter? Would you mind to elaborate?

Comment: Quoting and escapes are part of the csv protocol. For instance, what if a column is `"embedded comma, should not split this column"`? CSV parses deal with this, which is why we use them instead of just splitting.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer and removed any reference from mine regarding scalability of yours. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: If you use `csv` to handle the escaping ,then this solution is good.